# Android share intent of copy to clipboard

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I want to detect which share action is selected in my app

my share method:

```
public void share(String subject, String message) {

        List<Intent> shareIntentsLists = new ArrayList<Intent>();
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

        List<ResolveInfo> resInfos = getCurrentActivity().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);
        if (!resInfos.isEmpty()) {
            for (ResolveInfo resInfo : resInfos) {
                String packageName = resInfo.activityInfo.packageName;

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, resInfo.activityInfo.name));
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("text/plain");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
                intent.setPackage(packageName);
                shareIntentsLists.add(intent);
            }

            if (!shareIntentsLists.isEmpty()) {
                Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(shareIntentsLists.remove(0), "");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, shareIntentsLists.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
                getCurrentActivity().startActivity(chooserIntent);
            }

        }

    }
```

if put url link to message parameter and would show copy button to copy url to clipboard
like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uz5Pe.png)

How do I detect this copy button is pressed?

Because this button is not created in shareIntentsLists